# How to write a more optimized and simple query - Parent Child Relation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

I have a table of medical data which has relations (similar to parent and child).
For the sake of simplicity, I have considered a table with actual parent-child relationships.
Below is the table:

Table Name: Relations

```
Parent | Child
------ | ------
Mike   |John
Aliss  |John
John   |Chris
Brad   |David
Kate   |Brad
Alexa  |Shawn
Matt   |Thoa
```

I have written the query that gets me the GrandParent, Parent and Grandchild relationship.

```
SELECT t1.grandchild, 
       t2.grandparent,
       t1.parent,
       t2.child
FROM   (SELECT child AS Grandchild, 
               parent 
        FROM   relations 
        WHERE  parent IN (SELECT DISTINCT( r.parent ) 
                          FROM   relations r 
                                 JOIN relations t 
                                   ON r.parent = t.child)) AS t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT parent AS Grandparent, 
                          child 
                   FROM   relations 
                   WHERE  child IN (SELECT DISTINCT( r.parent ) 
                                     FROM   relations r 
                                            JOIN relations t 
                                              ON r.parent = t.child)) AS t2 
               ON t1.parent = t2.child 
ORDER  BY t1.grandchild;
```

Here is the catch, now the actual data has 30015924 rows and when I run the report using the above query it takes forever to get the data.

I saw the execution plans and there are many "Nested Loops" and Lazy spools.
I am trying to write a more efficient query which is faster to execute on a large dataset.

Will Union for separate relationships work. 
Is this the most efficient query I have written or are there some better versions of it?

Thank you.

Comment: The DISTINCT keyword will make it run slow. If it isn't needed you can take it out. Also is the table indexed in anyway?

Comment: No indexes on table, as it is very frequently updated and inserted.

Comment: What version of sql server are you working with? What indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: What's the desired result for this sample data?

Comment: I am getting the desired result, only it is very slow in execution

Comment: Well, I'm sure you do, but we don't see it here... Help us help you by providing the most basic example we can work with - DDL+DML for sample data, and desired results.

Comment: Put the proper indexes on your table.  Frequent updates is not a valid reason for not having the correct keys and indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a much simpler (and probably better performance-wise) query to get the exact same result:

First, create and populate sample data (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE relations
(
    Parent varchar(10),
    Child varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO relations VALUES

('Mike', 'John'),
('Aliss', 'John'),
('John', 'Chris'),
('Brad', 'David'),
('Kate', 'Brad'),
('Alexa', 'Shawn'),
('Matt', 'Thoa')
```

The query:

```
SELECT  sg.child as grandchild,
        fg.Parent as grandparent,
        fg.child as parent,
        sg.Parent as parent
FROM relations as fg -- stands for first generation
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT parent, child
    FROM relations
) as sg ON fg.child = sg.parent -- second generation
```

Results:

```
grandchild  grandparent parent  parent
Chris       Mike        John    John
Chris       Aliss       John    John
David       Kate        Brad    Brad
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/TMTVC73606) (I've pasted your query there as well to compare the results.)

Comment: Thank you... I will be sure to put in the create statements next time

Comment: And the query? Does it help?

Comment: Yes the query runs much faster than mine. Also I have created indexes on the table which I guess is helping with performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have often found that using unions have sped up query times tremendously over the use of nested, derived queries.